# Knockout: Cannot map computed observables after an Ajax call

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I have a view model with an Ajax call to save data:

```
ViewModel = function (data) {
  contractsAutocompleteUrl = data.ContractsAutocompleteUrl;
  var self = this;
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, lineMapping, self);

  self.save = function() {
        self.isBeingSaved(true);
        $.ajax({
            url: data.SaveUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.viewModel != null) {
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.viewModel, lineMapping, self);
                };
            }
        });
    },
```

I have some computed variables:

```
self.TotalSaturdayHrs = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var result = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Lines(),
        function(line) {
            result = addNumbers(result, line.SaturdayHrs());
        });
    return result;
}),
self.TotalSundayHrs = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var result = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Lines(),
        function(line) {
            result = addNumbers(result, line.SundayHrs());
        });
    return result;
}),
```

.
.
.
(all the way to Friday)

And a computed GrandTotal:

```
self.GrandTotalHrs = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var result = addNumbers(0, self.TotalSaturdayHrs());
    result = addNumbers(result, self.TotalSundayHrs());
    result = addNumbers(result, self.TotalMondayHrs());
    result = addNumbers(result, self.TotalTuesdayHrs());
    result = addNumbers(result, self.TotalWednesdayHrs());
    result = addNumbers(result, self.TotalThursdayHrs());
    result = addNumbers(result, self.TotalFridayHrs());
    return result;
}),
```

Now after the Ajax call, the computed observables TotalSaturdayHrs are no longer computed observables, they are simply properties and so my GrandTotal calculation throws an exception.
Why is that and how do I fix this?

Comment: My first guess would be that the server sends `TotalSaturdayHrs` (etc) properties in the POST response and the mapping plugin subsequently overrides your viewmodel.

Comment: Not strictly related, but please tell me that `addNumbers()` does not look like `function addNumbers(a, b) { return a + b; }`.

Comment: var addNumbers = function (result, number) {
    if (number === null || number === "") {
        return result;
    }

    return result + parseFloat(number);
}

Comment: That is the same as `result += +number;`, entirely without needing a function call at all.

Comment: Thank you, that is much better

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your question. (I see you have a couple of other "open" questions, it would be a decent move of you to look though them as well.)

Comment: I have accepted your answer although the actual answer is buried in the comments. Your assistance has been very helpful.

Comment: I think the comments just re-iterate in slightly different wording what I have written in the answer. Setting the `ignore` list is not the solution, it's the work-around (or "hack"). Not letting the server send any clashing properties in the first place is the solution – and my answer says just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your `.save()` function should look like (I have a hunch that this will solve your issue):

```
ViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this,
        contractsAutocompleteUrl = data.ContractsAutocompleteUrl;

    self.isBeingSaved = ko.observable(false);
    self.Lines = ko.observableArray();

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, lineMapping, self);

    self.save = function() {
        self.isBeingSaved(true);
        return $.ajax({
            url: data.SaveUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.mapping.toJSON(self),   // !!!
            contentType: "application/json"
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (!data.viewModel) return;
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data.viewModel, lineMapping, self);
        }).fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
            // error handling
        }).always(function () {
            self.isBeingSaved(false);
        });
    };
}
```

`ko.mapping.toJSON()` will only turn those properties to JSON that also went into the original mapping. `ko.toJSON()` in the other hand converts all properties, even the calculated ones like `TotalSundayHrs`.

My wild guess would be that the server returns the same JSON object it had received in the POST, complete with all the ought-to-be-calculated properties like `TotalSundayHrs` - which then messes up the mapping in your response handler.

Comment: How should I set up the Total fields so that they can be recalculated by the computed functions when coming back to the client?

Comment: If I copy and paste the code for the computed functions into the done clause, then it works. But I do not want to have to do that.

Comment: The computed "total" properties can remain the way they are. You need to make sure that **either** the server response does not contain properties of the same name (like `TotalSundayHrs`) **or** that your mapping setup (`lineMapping`) is explicitly configured to ignore these properties (see the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#ignoring-certain-properties-using-ignore)).

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you for that. I am new to Knockout as you can probably tell!

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the data object coming from the server should never contain any property that your client viewmodel calculates. Equally, your client viewmodel should never send any calculated values to the server.